# ARC and EXC_BAD_ACESS with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have implemented a view in my app where I have a UITableView. It performs lazy loading of images from the internet and this view also has an exit button where I execute the following code:

```
-(IBAction) exit{

    NSArray *versionCompatibility = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if (![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed])
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I am using ARC in this ViewController and the problem is that, whenever I press the exit button when the UITableView is scrolling, then it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: What line does it give EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. This table is built using an NSMutableArray. Should I be deallocating something here?

Comment: It's very hard to tell without either more code, or where the EXC actually occurs. The debugger in Xcode should halt at the line it fails at.

Comment: Narrowed it down to a delegate method invoked by the class downloading my images. I guess I can take it from here. Will post my progress. :)

Comment: Just a note on `isBeingDismissed`. The documentation states that: This method returns `YES` only when called from inside the following methods:
`viewWillDisappear:`, `viewDidDisappear:` so I guess that evaluates to `NO` every time (even when the modal has been dismissed). You could try something like this perhaps: `if (self.modalViewcontroller)...`

Comment: By the way: using `NULL` or `nil` will have exactly the same result. If you do "Jump to Definition" on `nil`, you get `#define nil NULL`.